# Removing menu dosen't remove separator in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to remove a menu generated by a Wordpress plugin. Removing the menu isn't the problem but the menu leaves an empty menu separator / divider.

This is what the menu looks like:

[image]

This is my code for removing the menu:

```
remove_submenu_page('duplicator.php','duplicator.php'); //Sub menu
remove_submenu_page('duplicator.php','duplicator_diag_page'); //Sub menu
remove_submenu_page('duplicator.php','duplicator_support_page'); //Sub menu
remove_submenu_page('duplicator.php','duplicator_about_page'); //Sub menu
remove_menu_page('duplicator.php'); //Top menu
```

And then my menu looks like this:

[image]

Left is the menu area separator, but how to remove them?